# Shadcn-UI Form Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, zod

While Working on this project, I had to console.log the state i used which is   `const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState<string[]>([]);` `console.log(fileNames)`

but I keep getting an empty Array element consistently displaying in my DOM each time I click on the parent element.
[image]

so I tried Uploading A file to see what happens, but what I get is Miraculous. here is what I found:

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
```

Please help me out, thanks a lot.

`Here is my code below`

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "../ui/input";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  FileText,
  Frown,
  UploadCloud,
  XCircle,
} from "lucide-react";

const formSchema = z.object({
  files: z.array(
    z.object({
      name: z.string(),
      type: z.string().refine((value) => /\.(doc|docx|pdf)$/i.test(value), {
        message: "File must be a document or PDF",
      }),
    })
  ),
});

const AddFiles = () => {
  const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      files: [],
    },
  });

  const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files) {
      const names = Array.from(event.target.files).map((file) => file.name);
      setFileNames(names);
    }
  };

  const handleRemoveFile = (index: number) => {
    const updatedFileNames = fileNames.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
    setFileNames(updatedFileNames);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    //TODO:
  };

  console.log(fileNames);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="px-4 mb-8 bg-neutral-800/10 mx-2 py-2">
        {fileNames.length > 0 ? (
          fileNames.map((name, index) => (
            <li key={index} className="list-none flex items-center gap-2">
              <FileText size={20} />
              <p className="text-sm">{name}</p>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="text-red-500 ml-auto"
                onClick={() => handleRemoveFile(index)}
              >
                <XCircle size={20} />
              </button>
            </li>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className="text-center text-neutral-300 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2">
            <Frown size={20} />
            <p className=" text-sm">No FIle Uploaded</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="mx-2 bg-neutral-900/10 px-4 py-6 rounded-md">
        <Form {...form}>
          <form
            onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            className="flex flex-col items-center gap-y-6"
          >
            <div className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
              <UploadCloud />
              <p className="text-xs text-neutral-100">Upload Files</p>
            </div>
            <FormField
              name="files"
              render={({ field }) => {
                return (
                  <FormItem className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-4 col-span-2">
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        className="bg-neutral-900/20 border border-transparent disabled:opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed file:bg-transparent file:text-neutral-200 file:border-none file:outline-none file:text-xs placeholder:text-neutral-400 focus:outline-none hover:cursor-pointer text-xs font-light"
                        type="file"
                        accept="application/msword,text/plain,application/pdf"
                        multiple
                        {...field}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          handleFileChange(event);
                          field.onChange(event);
                        }}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                );
              }}
            />

            <Button size="sm" className="px-8 py-1 bg-[#1d78f2] text-white">
              Add
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddFiles;
```

Comment: Can we see your input component?

Answer (score 4):

in the input component add the following

```
value={field.value ?? ''}
```

make sure its after the

```
{...field}
```

this should fix it

Answer (score 1):

simply add name="files" in the input component. your input component will look like this

```html
<Input
                        // ...other field

                        name= "files" // add this
                        {...field}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          handleFileChange(event);
                          field.onChange(event);
                        }}
                      />
```

explanation:

1. the problem occurred because input tag doesn't has initial/default value.
2. in your case, you already declared the default value in this code:

```html
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      files: [], // you named it "files"
    },
  });
```

but you should also assign the <input name: "declared name"/>. otherwise the code wouldn't be connected.

if you only added value={field.value ?? ''} without the input name, you will get another error which your form can't get the value.